# Stylelint not warning about !important

Tags: javascript, styled-components, stylelint

I have a project that make use of styled-components and I just have installed `Stylelint` following the official guide[1].

My `.stylelintrc.json` already have ***declaration-no-important*** set to `true` but seems have no effect, because I have one component that make use of `!important` (see bellow)

```
{
  "processors": ["stylelint-processor-styled-components"],
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-recommended", "stylelint-config-styled-components"],
  "rules": {
      "declaration-no-important": true
  }
}
```

```
$ ag important
lib/components/molecules/Checkbox/Checkbox.styles.ts
24:      border-color: #7e77a1 !important;
```

What I need to do to ***Stylelint*** warn me about the use of `!important`?

1 - https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#stylelint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this instead?

```
'declaration-no-important': [true, { 'severity': 'warning' }]
```